# DateBox close on back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using [Jquery CalBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) for an android application using cordova and jquery mobile. It works perfectly but the thing is after pop up the calender if I press button if goes to previous page. But what I need is, when I press back button calender should close. Is there any way to achieve that option for calender pop up?

Comment: Check weather your calander is open if open just preventDefault and close it.

Comment: yes, its opening and works fine. Where I can put this event preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use build in `preventDefault()' method.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you use Google developer tools or something similar to look at the CSS markup of the Calbox div when it is open and when it is closed.  If you find the differentiating attribute, great.

Then, in your device ready you can put a function that hooks into the back button like this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
}
```

In this block, you can put the `preventDefault()` to disable it from performing the back operation.  In addition, you can hide the calendar by setting the display attribute you have identified earlier. I had to do this for a datepicker and I set the display attribute:

```
if ($('#ui-datepicker-div').css("display") === "block") {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css("display", "none");
}
```

Good luck!